# Is there a way to make a noise generation algorithm anything other than O(n^2)?

Tags: python, random

I was looking into big 0 notation and was considering this in context for this algorithm:

```
from guizero import App, Text, Slider
import random
import numpy as np

app = App(title="Noise Generator", width=500, height=500, layout="grid")

def randomGen(rows,columns):
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            ranNum = random.randint(1,8)
            if ranNum == 1:
                output = Text(app, text="#", grid=[row, column], color="red")
            elif ranNum == 2:
                output = Text(app, text="#", grid=[row, column], color="blue")
            elif ranNum == 3:
                output = Text(app, text="#", grid=[row, column], color="green")
            elif ranNum == 4:
                output = Text(app, text='#', grid=[row, column], color="yellow")
            else:
                output2 = Text(app, text="#", grid=[row,column])

rows = int(input("Input no. of rows: "))
columns = int(input("Input no. of columns: "))
randomGen(rows,columns)
app.display()
```

From my understanding, my function is O(n^2) due to the two for loops. I was hoping to make a similar result with a lower O factor so I can scale the input to larger values. Would it be possible?

P.S. I am not quite sure if calling this a "Noise Generator" is an accurate statement, its just an algorithm that prints out different coloured "#" in random patterns.

I have tried researching different methods for the same program but couldn't quite find anything!

Comment: You keep defining and replacing `Text`  objects without using or saving them, so *as written*, you can eliminate all the earlier iterations and just create a single value in O(1) time. But if you actually *want* O(n\*\*2) different `Text` objects, then you need to store them all separately and you absolutely can't generate them faster than O(n**2) time.

Comment: (Or does `Text(app,..)` implicitly store the object in the given app, so that the assignment to `output` is actually unimportant?)

Comment: As an aside, you can use something like `color = random.choices(["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", None], [1, 1, 1, 4]); Text(app, text="#", grid=[row, column], color=color)` to eliminate the `if` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I can provide anything better, but I will highlight I think your current solution is O(m*n) time, as it is dependent on rows and columns, which may be different. O(n**2) implies two nested loops of the same length.

Comment: @chepner `guizero` is a GUI library like `tkinter`. `Text` is analogous to tkinter's `Label`. So it's creating a bunch of text fields in a grid.

Comment: Then O(n\*\*2) is a *lower* bound on your complexity, because your "output" contains O(n**2) objects. (You are meeting this lower bound because `Text` itself takes O(1) time relative to the number of rows and columns in the grid.)